# How in per packet multipath routing implemented in openflow? Is flow table updated after each packet transfer?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, mininet, openflow, ryu

I am trying to do multipath routing using per packet in openflow. I do not know how are multipaths used to deliver data on per packet basis. Is flow table updated everytime or group table does per packet delivery?

Answer (score 0):

Each flow entry may have an **idle timeout** and or a **hard timeout** associated with it.
The idle timeout and a hard timeout control the removal of a flow entry from the OpenFlow table. If either value is non-zero, the switch must note the flow entry's arrival time, as it may need to evict the entry later. A non-zero **idle_timeout** entry field causes the flow entry to be removed after the given number of seconds, if no packet has been matched by the flow. A non-zero **hard_timeout** field causes the flow entry to be removed after the given number of seconds, regardless of how many packets it has matched.

**Hard timeout**: The absolute timeout after which the flow is removed from the device.

**Idle timeout**: The absolute timeout in which if there are no packets hitting the flow for the duration, then flow is removed from the device.